# how to reference another file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to put all of my frequently used functions into a 'kind of' library file and reference it in other .m file. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you might want to look into is [packages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynt_-1.html) as a way to organize your functions and classes. From the documentation:

> Packages are special folders that can
>   contain class folders, function and
>   class definition files, and other
>   packages. Packages define a scope
>   (sometimes called a namespace) for the
>   contents of the package folder. This
>   means function and class names need to
>   be unique only within the package.
>   Using a package provides a means to
>   organize classes and functions and to
>   select names for these components that
>   other packages can reuse.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to previous answers I'd recommend to add Content.m file as a Table of content for a package/directory. See the entry in Mike's blog and follow the links to MATLAB documentation:

[Your Table of Contents](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/01/26/your-table-of-contents/)